# Deploying a WAR file gives me a 404 Status Code on Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment

I am fairly new to Tomcat. I just managed to build a project and exported it as a WAR file. I tried manually copying a WAR file to the Tomcat folder then restarting. It created the folder structure and everything but I get a 404 Status code when I try to reach the application. I tried deploying it through the Tomcat Admin panel but I'm seeing the same behavior. Am I doing anything fundamentally wrong?

Comment: What is your `request.getContextPath()` gives you? Are you doing this `http://localhost:8080/ContextPath/` (where contextPath is `request.getContextPath()`. If you are, then please check your web.xml for your configuration.

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question: If I cannot deploy the app, how can I execute it at this point?

Comment: Look into the log file. Maybe there is an exception when the app gets deployed.

Comment: Did you configure a default page correctly. Otherwise try the full path of page `/myapp/page.jsp`, or whatever the proper extension is `.jsf`, `.html`...

Comment: provide the complete path instead of just http://localhost:8080/"War-file-name"

Comment: If it is a springboot application check if the application class extends SpringBootServletInitializer this solved my error

Answer (score 17):

Assuming that you have full privileges with the Tomcat installation, try going to `http://localhost:8080/manager/html/`, if you don't know the password to get into that area, look for the `tomcat-users.xml` file in your `${tomcat-installation}/conf` directory, and that should have it.  If it has no entries in it then you will want to add an entry like the following to it:

```
<user username="username" password="password" roles="admin,manager" />
```

See whether your application shows up in that screen, and if it does, click on the link and see if that gets you anywhere.  If it doesn't, then I suggest following ifishers's advice, and looking at the log  files to see if it lists any errors.

But long story short, most likely something is screwed up with your project's `web.xml`

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem but only during deploying the app for the 1st time as root app.If I restart the server then i'm able to access the app's landing page. Tried your approach and I'm being redirected to the app's home page on clicking the link in URL "http://localhost:8080/manager/html/".....Any idea what I'm doing wrong??

Answer (score 13):

In more recent times, this condition might occur if JAVA_HOME points to an earlier version of Java than the code in the WAR. Tomcat might use JAVA_HOME to determine JRE_HOME it shows after running startup.bat in Tomcat's BIN directory. While Tomcat may be happy itself with the Java version it gets, for the application this might not be sufficient. In my case, Tomcat 8.0.49 was running alright with JDK1.7, while the application was not initializing at all (yes, it was a Spring Boot application, WAR was being unpacked, but that's all) - without giving any errors. After setting JAVA_HOME to the location of JDK1.8, the problem was solved.

Comment: I just ran into this issue. An updated war built with JDK1.8 was inadvertently deployed in an old environment running on JDK1.7.

Answer (score 10):

I have the same problem.
My problem is my application name and war file name are different.
I have change war file name to my application name.

Here, when your application is deployed tomcat automatically extract your war file with same name. In my case my service name is my-web-service(i.e.https://localhost:8080/my-web-service/) and my war file name is MY-java-connector-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war(this is my project folder name). Now tomcat is looking for my-web=service folder and it finds epicor-java-connector-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT folder. so rename the folder to my-web=service.war and it is working.

Comment: To avoid this maybe you can try with this in you pom.xml <finalName>app-name</finalName> inside the build tag and after that your target files will be renamed to this app-name that you defined.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, my problem was that I was copying the file via sftp straight into the webapps dir of tomcat which may have caused a polling issue causing it to not deploy correctly.
Tomcat monitors the webapps dir and when it sees the .xml it will crack on and do its thing, problem is that maybe everything hasn't been copied across yet. :(

Best to create a staging folder, move or copy the war to that folder and then use linux mv command to move it into the webapps - mv is atomic so tomcat won't do anything until the operation is complete.

Magic.

Credit goes to a very very random post that I found on javarance which in turn lead to : http://pub.admc.com/howtos/tomcat/ch02.html#stagedir-section

Hope this helps someone else :)

Answer (score 6):

If your'e using Spring-Boot like me to create your WAR file make sure to add the following to your main Application file.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class serverTestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(serverTestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(serverTestApplication.class);
    }
}
```

I was stuck on this for awhile, looked through dozens of guides. This is the video that finally showed me I never configured my application properly:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05EKZ9Xmfws

Answer (score 4):

My best guess is that you have not configured the welcome files in your web.xml. If you go to /app/ you need to have some default file available. Typically, people either created an index.html or they have welcome file settings to point the user to the correct jsp.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem, too.

My simple roundabout solution is to change docBase path.

problem occurs when

```
docBase=".../tomcat/webapps/app_name.war";
```

problem solved with

```
docBase=".../tomcat/webapps/app_foldername/web"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with tomcat and just fixed it by forcing my IDE to create a web.xml file.  Mine was missing.  It would deploy the project but I would still get the 404 error.  I read through several of these tutorials but to no avail.  I read somewhere that the web.xml file needed to be configured correctly.  Went to find the web.xml in the WEB-INF folder, and there was no folder and no web.xml file.  I did a quick google on how to create on using my IDE and then compiled my program with the web.xml output, and it fixed the problem for me.  Hope that helps.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I had this problem and fixed it by discovering I was accessing the wrong host, like "http://wronghost:8080/why_is_this_war_not_there" so if it says "XX.war successfully deployed" in catalina.out/localhost.*.out that may be a hint for followers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  In my case there were no errors in the log files, I had a welcome page defined, it was listed in the Tomcat manager webapp, and it deployed and worked fine on my dev machine.  However, visiting the app at  http://example.com/myApp  just returned a 404 error.

It turns out the problem was in the Apache config.  Apache didn't have a mount point, so it didn't know to proxy those requests to Tomcat.

Adding in the appropriate directive fixed the problem:

```
ProxyPass /myApp ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/myApp
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to face the same problem. Simply access the application using application name instead of the war file name. (***-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT). It will work.

Answer (score 0):

For those still encountering this error, it sometimes results because of port conflict with Apache Webserver using the same port 8080, as seen in the error

> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler
> initialization failed

> Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use

Stopping Apache resolves this. Use

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

or the related variant for your operating system, and try relaunching your application via Tomcat

Answer (score 0):

I installed tomcat and then placed *.war file in webapps folder. Updated the required conf/*.xml files as mentioned in the tutorials but when I trying to access my application on the server, I was getting Error- 404.

**Root cause for me:**
Apache Tomcat 10 was installed but my spring boot application was on 2.x.
So, I had to upgrade my project to 3.1.5 version and java version 17.
Once I updated the version, Error-404 was gone.

Answer (score 0):

**TRY UPGRADING YOUR VERSION OF APACHE TOMCAT**

I faced similar issues recently. It was after 3 days of painful experience that i realized that the version of apache tomcat (9.x) is not compatible with my web application. I had to upgrade to apache tomcat 10.x.

Answer (score -1):

If you have not created any welcome page like index.html JSP or whatever then create one. project must have an index page. I just created one say index.html and the problem is solved..

Answer (score -3):

Did you try

```
localhost:8080/app
```

assuming your war file is app.war?

edit for comment -- then your web.xml is screwed up.

Comment: Yeap... That is giving me the 404 code. If I try just `localhost:8080` it gives me the intro page...