# would like some guidance decrypting tomcat errors

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have these errors for tomcat 7. I am uploading to a server with JDK 1.6 and running Tomcat 7.02X
I keep getting these errors whatever i Do. what does this mean?

**error1**

> INFO: Deploying web application archive user2.war
>   Jun 8, 2012 2:51:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
>   SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[yuppie.com].StandardContext[/user2]]
>   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:932)

**Also it goes to this error**

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/yuppie/Populator : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class com.yuppie.Populator)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2824)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1150)

I apologize for listing out errors. I know its quite hated in this community, but I have no clue on these errors thats why. Thank you

**One last error**

> SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive user2.war
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[credify.me].StandardContext[/user2]]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:816)

Comment: The second one seems to be starting Tomcat using JDK of a lower version than the version of the class file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/yuppie/Populator : 
Unsupported  major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class com.yuppie.Populator) at 
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2824) 
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1150)
```

Reason for this is because your java file is compiled with a later version of the JDK (eg.Java 7) while your JRE is an earlier version (eg. Java 6).

Mayb you can fix this problem first to see if you have new errors.

If you are using external libraries, then it is likely that the external library was compiled with a more recent version of the Java Compiler, as compared to the JRE you are using. I would recommend you upgrade your JRE to the latest version.

Comment: Here is a previous answer which lists the major versions:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1096159/425406
This goes along nicely with your answer

Answer (score 1):

[LifecycleException](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/LifecycleException.html) indicates most probably you have a life cycle problem.

[UnsupportedClassVersionError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedClassVersionError.html) is thrown when the class file's version numbers are not supported.

[IllegalStateException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) is as the name says, the state of the Java Application isn't legal or appropriate to handle the current request.

Porbable Fixes:

UnsupportedClassVersionError : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2467356/828625

LifecycleException : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8512930/828625

IllegalStateException : https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50737

Comment: Eh, thank you Captain Obvious:)I think OP is able to read names of the exceptions...

Comment: @PetrMensik OP says : "I have no clue on these errors thats why."