# Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/JDBC_DBO]]

Tags: java, tomcat, catalina, executionexception, lifecycleexception

I get this Tomcat Error:

```
Sep 09, 2012 4:16:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
Information: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Products\jdk1.7.0_03\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Products/jdk1.7.0_03/jre/bin/client;C:/Products/jdk1.7.0_03/jre/bin;C:/Products/jdk1.7.0_03/jre/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Products\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Products\eclipse32;;.
Sep 09, 2012 4:16:54 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
Warnung: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:NAR_JDBC_DBO' did not find a matching property.
Sep 09, 2012 4:16:55 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
Information: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-80"]
Sep 09, 2012 4:16:55 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
Information: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 09, 2012 4:16:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
Information: Initialization processed in 1008 ms
Sep 09, 2012 4:16:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
Information: Starting service Catalina
Sep 09, 2012 4:16:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
Information: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.27
Sep 09, 2012 4:16:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
Schwerwiegend: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/NAR_JDBC_DBO]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:782)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/NAR_JDBC_DBO]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/RuleSet
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2308)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1760)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.getDeclaredFields(WebAnnotationSet.java:452)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:381)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:858)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5161)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.digester.RuleSet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
    ... 21 more

Sep 09, 2012 4:16:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
Schwerwiegend: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:675)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:782)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more

Sep 09, 2012 4:16:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
Schwerwiegend: Catalina.start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:675)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

Sep 09, 2012 4:16:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
Information: Server startup in 540 ms
```

What's the problem? I am using an Apache Tomcat 7 and the following 4 catalina jars are used:

- catalina.jar
- catalina-ant.jar
- catalina-ha.jar
- catalina-tribes.jar

Are any other JAR files missing?

Comment: for grails >= 4.x see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66370012/2634103

Answer (score 25):

You are missing `commons-digester3-3.2.jar` from [Apache Commons Digester](http://commons.apache.org/digester/download_digester.cgi). If you are using Maven you can add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

to your project dependencies.

**Update:**
The jar from the latest download page has a slightly different package structure to what your application expects. You can use [this older jar](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.5/commons-digester-1.5.jar) instead.

Comment: I added the jars into Apache Tomcat 7.0 but I get the same Error:-(

Comment: Is the error msg _exactly_ the same? It is possible that your app has been been properly re-deployed. Is the jar in WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: No, it is not exactly the same. look at this:

Comment: The jar is not in WEB-INF/lib. Should it?

Comment: yes, but it's an older post ;-) you can see here the new post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341648/setpropertiesruleserver-service-engine-host-context-setting-property-source).

Comment: I had a look in the jar and the package structure has **digester3** in the package structure. Can you try the one in my update?

Comment: Could you Please answer on this issue too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35825331/java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror-class-org-springframework-core-type-clas/35831642# ?

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem in my tomcat server but when  i check deeply  i found that i add a new tag in my web.xml file and the server doesn't accept it so check  your file to if any update happened then restart your tomcat and will be good .

Comment: thanks, this solved my issue, i missed out a '/' in the web.xml.

Answer (score 8):

If u r using eclipse then delete tomcat server and Server folder then reconfigure
those two..

Answer (score 7):

web module -> Properties -> Deployment Assembly -> (add folder "src/main/webapp", Maven Dependencies and other needed module)

Answer (score 6):

I was getting this while running in Java EE Eclipse.  None of the answers here helped.  What finally did it for me was:

1. maven clean
2. start tomcat in debug

I kept doing a maven clean install and error wouldn't go away.  Weird.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using dynamic web project then make sure you have added the jar file as **commons-logging-1.2.jar** in "WebContent > WEB-INF > lib" folder.

Along with you can do few more step as:

1. Right click on project > Properties > Targeted Runtimes > Choose Apache Tomcat server from list > Apply > Ok.
2. Go to Servers tab > Right click on server configured > Properties > General > Switch location(eg- /Servers/Tomcat/.....) > Apply > Ok.

That's all!

Answer (score 5):

I guess you are working with a Dynamic Web Project, because you mentioned de folder WEB-INF/lib in a comment; if yes, make sure your not putting any *-servlet jar file inside this folder or other jar already provided by the container, in this case Tomcat.
   Plus: Once I used jersey-servlet.jar, and I needed to remove it from the lib folder in order to Tomcat start without problems; then I use just jersey-bundle.jar and it works well.

Answer (score 5):

Well I am not sure what actual cause is but I have done this way for the same error. I have comment out this annotation for the servelet and its working.

```
//@WebServlet("/HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
```

Dont know that could be proper solution of not. but this worked and another thing that can be test is add servlet jar into class path. That might work.

Comment: Does anyone know why this worked? It did work for me too (Tomcat 8 w/ Eclipse)

Comment: Same for me, I wrote wrong the urlPatterns... 
Thank you!

Comment: It works for me too... Thank you! I had the same issue like SeReGa... used 'urlPatterns' parameter in wrong way... I didn't add a '/' in the starting position.

Answer (score 4):

For me, I did `mvn clean` and then restart the tomcat. It worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, even after trying "mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0" and "mvn clean install". But after I clean my server it just worked. So maybe after you are sure you have all the dependency needed try to clean the server.

Comment: Clean didn't work. But after running it on another server, it ran nicely.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Check your application is building successfully by running `mvn clean install` over your project and correct all the errors

Usually this error comes when you have dependencies which are not present on your classpath.

If you are using tomcat maven plugin then try deploying your war using following command

```
tomcat7:run-war-only
```

Answer (score 3):

Even I had same problem

`Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/]`

I have added respective dependency at very begenining it had worked for me.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. After much searching I decided to reconfigure my server in Eclipse. (ie clean it as suggested by Benson
Go to Project Explorer, Servers and Delete (ensure you also delete contents on disk)
Then go to Windows->Preferences->Server->Runtime Environments
Remove the Tomcat server and then add it back in.

This cleans up the server.xml, webxml, context.xml files. It basically rewrites them. Something in one of mine (or multiple things) were awry and this fixes it. A bit simpler than trying to find the offending tags/lines

Answer (score 2):

Windows -> Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environment -> Delete all Apache servers available. Add the same. Now run your application on server. Its done 
:)

Answer (score 1):

I met this error and tried several ways you guys mentioned still didn't work. I even tried to reinstall Tomcat, still have this error.

The last thing I did was to remove the entire Netbeans and Tomcat. It finally worked out. I know this isn't a good way to solve problem, but if you are really hurry and don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

all i found solution for whatever you all get the exception like..
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]..

the problem with bulid path of the jars..

To over come this problem.. place all jars in "WebContent/lib" whatever you need to in your project.
 i hope it will useful to you...

Answer (score 1):

It is because one or all of the maven dependencies got corrupted. Just delete corrupted dependencies or all the maven local dependencies and restart the eclipse and update project.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this maven dependency in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]

Already all robotet. My pom.xml:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.springapp
    war
    1.0-SNAPSHOT
    war
    rent</name>-->

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.2.6.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Spring Security-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--JUnit-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>war</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

I configure a servlet in web.ml , again i configured same servlet using annotations in servlet class. I removed annotation based configuration then server started properly.

Answer (score 0):

server.xml is created when you publish a project.Now If you add more dependency later then server.xml will not be able to catch it until and unless it is refreshed again. Sometimes you need to rebuild context/config file also.
First you try to clean the work directory.If it doesn't work then delete server and Server folder,then reconfigure those two.

Answer (score 0):

In intelliJ I had two different tomcat versions/folders specified for Tomcat Home and Tomcat base directory in app server configuration

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem which was caused by this nested exception

```
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
```

Looking closely found that it is due to the spring version which had a bad signature. Changed spring version to 4.3.4, build and deployed. Everything worked.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Posting since this solution may help somebody:

I faced a similar issue with the Tomcat 8.0. Seems the tomcat jar files might have corrupted. So I just downloaded the new Tomcat 8.0, unzipped it and configured it with my eclipse IDE. Also check the Project Facet under the preference menu.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with the deployment descriptor and dependencies that you are using.

I was having the same issue that I resolved by doing these things.
Update your POM.XML

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Also, add this code inside your build tag under the POM.XML only Since Container needs to know that where is your resource file configured.

```
<build>
        <finalName>HatchWaysAppAPI</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/resources</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Change your resource folder according to your requirement.

Your Web.xml should be like this.

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>HatchWaysAppAPI Maven Webapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.hatchwaysapi.mainController</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HatchWaysAppAPI Maven Webapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/v1/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Note This configuration only for the maven if you not using maven than ignore Pom.XML just do config of the Web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed all jars of spring version in lib folder of WEB INF, it works for me if u are using maven project just update dependency with different version it might work

Answer (score 0):

After spending lot of time on internet. I found that NONE of the option
worked for I tried
Right click on the server -> Clean. didn't work.

What worked is:

You just to add`<absolute-ordering/>`  tag to your **web.xml** just under the `<display-name>` tag and it should work.[for more detail click here](http://After%20spending%20lot%20of%20time%20on%20internet.%20I%20found%20that%20NONE%20of%20the%20below%20option%20%20worked%20for%20I%20tried%20%20Right%20click%20on%20the%20server%20-%3E%20Clean.%20didn%27t%20work.%20%20What%20worked%20is:%20You%20just%20to%20add%20%3Cabsolute-ordering%20/%3E%20tag%20to%20your%20web.xml%20just%20under%20the%20%3Cdisplay-name%3E%20tag%20and%20it%20should%20work.)

Answer (score 0):

Just clean your server  (in my case I was using Tomcat):

```
mvn clean
mvn install
```

Answer (score -1):

The filter name I mentioned in my web.xml doesn't exist. After correcting the typo it worked perfectly.