# APACHE 8 Java 8 Maven Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext

Tags: maven, tomcat, java-8

Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext

Comment: Refer this link:[it worked for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50522981/7527189)

Answer (score 0):

## 1) Go to Project Properties

[Right Click on project name]

[image: Step 1]

## 2) Search and Click On 'Deployment Assembly'

[image: Add package]

## 3) Add your src package.

## 4 Done !!!