# Tomcat & Eclipse : Can't run the server

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I had a working webapp but my project's Maven architecture wasn't correct so I decided to create a new one (I named it asteriskManagerV3).
I copied my code into it and tried to run it with Tomcat but I always get this error : 
[error when running the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bqn74.png)

I tried lot of solutions but none worked.

Here is my web.xml in Tomcat :

```
 ...
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MaServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>be.wavenet.MaServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>


<!-- The mapping for the default servlet -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MaServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/actions</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
...
```

web.xml in my project (/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>asteriskManagerV3</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
     <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
     <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
     <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>MaServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>MaServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>MaServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MaServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/actions</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

In Eclipse console I ge this error :

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/asteriskManagerV3]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/asteriskManagerV3]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@3fe4e7f4]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4868)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5003)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [/home/wvn/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/asteriskManager] is not valid
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(StandardRoot.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:706)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more

Mar 22, 2018 11:59:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/asteriskManager]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/asteriskManager]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@2cd3ffa7]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4868)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5003)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [/home/wvn/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/asteriskManagerV3] is not valid
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(StandardRoot.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:706)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more

Mar 22, 2018 11:59:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:681)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:948)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Mar 22, 2018 11:59:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:681)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:948)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

Mar 22, 2018 11:59:01 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mar 22, 2018 11:59:01 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Mar 22, 2018 11:59:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Catalina]
Mar 22, 2018 11:59:01 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mar 22, 2018 11:59:01 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

PS : I'm using Tomcat 8.5.28

Comment: are using maven or directly added jars?

Comment: this should get you started: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [/home/wvn/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/asteriskManagerV3] is not valid

Comment: @SandipND maven

Comment: clean **.m2** folder clean server from your tomcat, update maven & try

Comment: @Stultuske I saw it but when I look into this "/home/wvn/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps" folder there is no "asteriskManagerV3" only a folder named root.

Comment: @SandipND By "clean .m2", you mean delete the "repository" folder that is inside or run mvn clean or something else? Sorry ah ah! Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: refer **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340128/failed-to-start-component-standardenginecatalina-standardhostlocalhost-stan/35646457**

Comment: @SandipND This person had an "Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/RuleSet" error. I looked at proposed solutions and unfortunatly none worked. My error is "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [/home/wvn/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/asteriskManager] is not valid".

Comment: Remove the ` <servlet-mapping>` tag from your `web.xml` (projects). Just keep the `servlet` tag. See what happens.

Comment: Nice try but it didn't work. Thanks for having tried though. (Still struggling with this error btw...)