# Tomcat v7.0 server failed to start

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7

So, I'm trying to work with a tomcat v7.0 server. I have already worked with a tomcat v8.0 server but because hosting providers don't support tomcat v8.0 I need to create a v7.0 project.

[image: Library]

But when I try to start the server, this is what happens:

***NOTE: I do not have a servlet-api.jar in my WEB-INF/lib***

```
Sep 29, 2015 8:59:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:691)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 11 more
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512588/tomcat-lifecycleexception-when-deploying.

Comment: There the problem is a wrong servlet-mapping. I do not have any servlets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check **{TOMCAT_HOME}/logs/catalina.out** for more possible errors in this scenario. I think this is because of the wrong configurations in server-config. Previously you have used the tomcat 8 then it will still have the previous configurations. So clean full project and remove all the servers then start with Tomcat 7.0

Answer (score 2):

Delete existing server in the "Servers" view (tab) of eclipse.

Also delete servers folder in navigator/project explorer in eclipse.

Recreate server, it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have anything deployed on the server while are you starting it? Try this:

1. Right click on the server/Add and remove...
2. Remove every project from server and click ok.
3. Right click on the server/Clean.
4. Start the server again.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse double click and open server.
open Modules view.

List of web modules can be seen.

Remove unnecessary modules, save and retry.