# how to debug Tomcat LifecycleException

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

i am building a new server and trying to get an existing app running on tomcat 8

when i try to start tomcat i tail out catalina.out

i just get this generic exception.

I am looking for how to increase the logging level or other suggestions on how to get better debug information catalina.out ( the top layer of the exception)

> 9-Nov-2018 01:39:48.261 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:596)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1805)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

this is the other part of the exception

> 9-Nov-2018 01:39:48.266 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Error deploying configuration descriptor /opt/java/apache-tomcat-8.5.6/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml
>    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:728)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:596)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1805)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

thanks

Comment: In most cases you'll find additional Exception Stacktrace(s) containing the root cause when you scroll up your log.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tomcat: LifecycleException when deploying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512588/tomcat-lifecycleexception-when-deploying)

Comment: Selaron-  , i am actually emptying the log file each time and no.. there is no info more above.

Comment: yes "Tomcat: LifecycleException when deploying"  is close, but the problem is i need more info. there is nothing in the catalina.out the points me to what or why my app is not starting

Comment: hmm this is odd, can you paste a full log? And no additional log files for your web application? BTW: you can increase log level in `apache-tomcat/conf/logging.properties`