# Error 404 while deploying application in Tomcat

Tags: java, html, web-applications, tomcat7

When I try to deploy this application 'Random', it gives 404 error. I checked the manager app and it says the application could not be started.

I tried restarting the tomcat service, Tried to deploy it from the manager app.

My deployment descriptor:

```xml
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>NewResponse</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>NewResponse</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>OldResponse</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>OldResponse</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>NewResponse</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/next</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>OldResonse</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/next2</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-list>index.html</welcome-list>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

FAIL - Application at context path [/Random] could not be started

FAIL - Encountered exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Random]]]

Comment: You should [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512588/tomcat-lifecycleexception-when-deploying/40728622)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512588/tomcat-lifecycleexception-when-deploying/40728622

Comment: That was helpful, I found the error,there was a servlet missing and I have mapped that in the descriptor. I had previously undeployed the folder without creating a backup.