# War file working on my PC but 404 error with older Tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, war, java-7

I had to develop an app with Flutter for my dissertation. The app was an update and an extension of an old app devepoled by another student of my university, 2 years ago.
He developed also the **backend**  that was written in Java using Spring and Maven.
Developing my app, I had to do some changes and additions in his code.

Some days ago I tried to export the **backend project as a war file** compiling with the JDK 15 (during the developing I used the Intellij's build-in Tomcat to test the new features) and I did the deploy on my Tomcat and I got error 404.
After reading many posts about this error on this site I found the solution by simply installing and compiling with java 12.
At that point, excited by the idea of finally being able to use my application and start the tests necessary for my thesis, I deployed the **same** war file to the Tomcat running on university server and I got error 404 again:

"HTTP Status 404 - /backend-api/
type Status report

message /backend-api/

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)"

I tried to install the same JDK (1:7:0 79) that was used by the developer of the backend during his dissertation, but the problem wasn't solved.

In the second anwser of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365135/deploying-a-war-file-gives-me-a-404-status-code-on-tomcat) it seems that they are talking about a similar problem, the point is that I can't modify any setting of the server of my univeristy and, right now, I can not even access to the logs of Tomcat.

I think the problem may be an outdated version of the JDK or Tomcat running on the university server.

But what seems strange to me is that the old version of the backedn is still running on that server and working without problems, and I have not made any changes to the configuration files, but only added a couple of functions.

Do you have any suggestions for me to solve the problem or understand what the cause is?
In a few days I should graduate and without my backend the application is not usable.

On my PC i deployed the war file on Tomcat 7.0.107 with JVM version 1.8.0_271-b09, while the university is running Apache Tomcat / 7.0.52 (Ubuntu) with JVM version 1.7.0_79-b14.

Thanks a lot to anyone who takes their time for trying to help me.

Comment: For helping with this, it's necessary to check in deep your code. If you are on a hurry (it seems), the standard approach is to clone the working environment, and do the changes one by one. The error 404 maybe means that the backend is failing (but it seems is only a problem with the resource name).

Comment: So I should install the same version of Tomcat and JDK on my machine and try to see what happens?
Thank you for your reply

Comment: Yes. For this using virtual machines is really helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, by the way at the end I solved the problem changing java version from 1.8 to 1.7 in pom.xml.
Have a nice day